# Is there a way to not apply spring animations to children objects?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-spring

Is there a way to have for example a div that fades in and out (to use for alternating through different backgrounds let's say). And have its childen (text lets say) at full opacity all the time?

```
{transitions((style, 
<animated.div
  class={
  bg[i] + " bg-fixed bg-cover absolute h-full w-screen bg-no-repeat"
  }
  style={{
  ...style,
  }}
 >
   <TextComponentHere/>
</animated.div>
))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact, you can. Instead of using `opacity: 0.8`, you should use `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)`. `Opacity` generally refers to all of the parents children, while `rgba` values can be set for just a specific element, and have it's children be set otherwise.

Comment: How should this be written, from: { opacity: 0 }, enter: { opacity: 1 } I can't find anything about rgba and from to arguements in the documentation

Comment: Are you setting some type of background color on this element?

Comment: Yes I have a 3-image transition as a bg and on top of that I'm trying to lay over some text but if I add the text as a sibling and not as a child it is appearing behind the bg and if I add it as a child I see the same content 3 times because of the 3 backgrounds

Comment: And the z values are not working for some reason

Comment: So when you're setting your bg color, are you using a color name, such as `red` or `orange`, or are you using a `hex/rgb` value?

Comment: I was doing it with an image but I solved it thank you very much !